# Send output from terminal call via curl

Tags: php, curl, terminal

I have the following command line script right now:

```
df -h | curl -F stuff=test http://foo.com
```

Which will send an POST Request to foo.com. In the `$_POST` variable I have the following data set:

```
[stuff] => test
```

Now I want to change `test` with the output from `df -h` so I can see it in my `$_POST` variable.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried? This might accomplish the goal. Try it out and let me know.

```
curl -F "stuff=`df -h`" http://foo.com
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

```
df -h | xargs -I % curl -F stuff=% http://foo.com
```

Comment: It worked and it seems the cleaner way for me, but this command has sent 3 Requests to my server and only the first 3 lines out of 9. Is there a way to fix that?